# boost to_upper function of string_algo doesn't take into account the locale

Tags: c++, string, boost, internationalization

I have a problem with the functions in the string_algo package.

Consider this piece of code:

```
#include <boost/algorithm/string.hpp>
int main() {
   try{
      string s = "meißen";
      locale l("de_DE.UTF-8");
      to_upper(s, l);
      cout << s << endl;
   catch(std::runtime_error& e){
      cerr << e.what() << endl;
   }

   try{
      string s = "composición";
      locale l("es_CO.UTF-8");
      to_upper(s, l);
      cout << s << endl;
   catch(std::runtime_error& e){
      cerr << e.what() << endl;
   }
}
```

The expected output for this code would be:

```
MEISSEN
COMPOSICIÓN
```

however the only thing I get is

```
MEIßEN
COMPOSICIóN
```

so, clearly the locale is not being taken into account. I even try to set the global locale with no success. What can I do?

Comment: UTF-8 is a good format for transport. But not that great inside memory because it can by anything from 1 to 4 characters per code point. In memory it is easier to use UCS-2 which is fixed size (Note UTF-16 is again variable size because of surrogate pairs).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

std::toupper assumes a 1:1 conversion, so there is no hope for the ß to SS case, Boost.StringAlgo or not.

Looking at [StringAlgo's code](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_41_0/boost/algorithm/string/case_conv.hpp), we see that it does use the locale (Except on Borland, it seems). So, for the other case, I'm curious: What is the result of `toupper('ó', std::locale("es_CO.UTF-8"))`on your platform?

Writing the above makes me think about something else: What is the encoding of the strings in your sources? UTF8? In that case, std::toupper will see two code units for 'ó', so there is no hope. Latin1? In that case, using a locale named ".UTF-8" is inconsistent.

Comment: my sources are encoding as utf8. When I try to use std::toupper('o', std::locale("es_CO.UTF-8")) I get a warning "multi-character character constant" and I don't get any answer but an error: terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::bad_cast'
  what():  std::bad_cast

Comment: As I write in my answer: toupper handles strings char by char. 'ó'  in UTF-8 is two bytes, so there is no hope that toupper yields something meaningful for that. You need to use an encoding where your characters can be represented in a single code unit. In the present case, I see two choices: Latin1 and char strings, or UTF-16 (or 32, depending on sizeof(wchar_t) on your platform) and wchar_t strings.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to the answer of Éric Malenfant -- `std::locale` facets works on single character. To get better result you may use `std::wstring` -- thus more characters would be converterd, but as you can see it is still not perfect (example ß).

I would suggest to give a try to Boost.Locale (new library for boost, not yet in boost), that does stuff

http://cppcms.sourceforge.net/boost_locale/docs/,

Especially see http://cppcms.sourceforge.net/boost_locale/docs/index.html#conversions that deals with the problem you are talking about.

Answer (score 0):

In the standard library there is std::toupper (which boost::to_upper uses) that operates on one character at a time.

This explains why the ß doesn't work. You didn't say which standard library and codepage you are using so I don't know why the ó didn't work.

What happens if you use wstring instead?

Answer (score 0):

You can use boost::locale.
[Here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/libs/locale/doc/html/index.html) is an example.